# need to transform array of objects from form to another in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

inputs array:

```
weekSchedules: [
          {
            dayId: 1,
            daySchedules: [
              {
                batchScheduleId: 1,
                Time: 12:00
              },
              {
                batchScheduleId: 1,
                ime: 12:30
              },
              {
                batchScheduleId: 2,
                Time: 13:00
              },
              {
                batchScheduleId: 2,
                Time: 13:30
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            dayId: 2,
            daySchedules: [
              {
                batchScheduleId: 1,
                Time: 12:00
              },
              {
                batchScheduleId: 1,
                Time: 12:30
              },
              {
                batchScheduleId: 2,
                Time: 13:00
              },
              {
                batchScheduleId: 2,
                Time: 13:30
              }
            ]
          }
         }
        ]

output array:


 [
    {
      batchScheduleId: 1,
      Time:[12:00,12.30],
      dayId: [1,2]
    },
    {
      batchScheduleId: 2,
      Time:[12:00,12.30],
      dayId: [1,2]
    }
]
```

i need transform input array objects to output array objects given below in angular typescript.
i tried using plain JavaScript but for that i have to write lots of code so i want simplify code to achieve this.

to acheive this i have to write multiple for loops and if condition but i want to avoid it and the solution should more generic so that i can use the same solution in multiple places just by changing the key. it would be better if the solution uses loadsh for this requirement and plain JavaScript approach is not required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use reduce function to avoid using the if and the for

```js
const inputObject = {weekSchedules:[{dayId:1,daySchedules:[{batchScheduleId:1,Time:"12: 00"},{batchScheduleId:1,Time:"12: 30"},{batchScheduleId:2,Time:"13: 00"},{batchScheduleId:2,Time:"13: 30"}]},{dayId:2,daySchedules:[{batchScheduleId:1,Time:"12: 00"},{batchScheduleId:1,Time:"12: 30"},{batchScheduleId:2,Time:"13: 00"},{batchScheduleId:2,Time:"13: 30"}]}]}


const flattenedBatch = inputObject.weekSchedules
  .reduce((prev, next) => [
  ...prev, ...next.daySchedules.map(({batchScheduleId, Time}) => ({batchScheduleId, dayId: next.dayId, Time}))

], [])

const groupedData = flattenedBatch.reduce((prev, next) => {
  const prevValue = prev?.[next.batchScheduleId] ?    prev[next.batchScheduleId].dayId : [];
  prevValue.push(next.dayId)
  
    const prevTime = prev?.[next.batchScheduleId] ?    prev[next.batchScheduleId].Time : [];
  prevTime.push(next.Time)
  
  return {...prev, [next.batchScheduleId]: {
    batchScheduleId: next.batchScheduleId,
    dayId: [...new Set(prevValue)],
    Time: [...new Set(prevTime)]
  }}
}, {});

const outputData = Object.values(groupedData)
console.log(outputData)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! but i also include time property in the array like below [
    {
      batchScheduleId: 1,
      Time:[12:00, 12.30]
      dayId: [1,2]
    },
    {
      batchScheduleId: 2,
      Time:[13:00,13:30],
      dayId: [1,2]
    }
]

Comment: Owen Kelvin, can you please help on the modified output as i mentioned in previous comment.

Comment: You can check amended solution

Comment: Thank you. i need on one more transformation of input array

output array
output array:
 [
    {
      day: 1,
      batchtime: [
        {
            time: 12:00, 12.30
             batch: 1
        }
        ]
      }
]